# Firebase SDK for Unity does not compile in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a project that uses the **Firebase SDK for Unity**, specifically the `FirebaseMessaging.unitypackage`, it's all fine on android, but I'm receiving **errors on the iOS build**.

---

### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to reproduce the error:

**Requirements:**

- iOS device (version 7.0 or later)
- Computer with macOS
- Xcode 8

**Steps:**

1. [Download](https://store.unity.com/download?ref=personal) the latest Unity version. (5.5.1f1 at this moment)
2. [Download](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) Firebase SDK for Unity.
3. Unzip the Firebase SDK for Unity.
4. Open Unity 5.5.1f1 and create a new project.
5. Go to *Assets > Import Package > Custom package...* , select the unzipped `FirebaseMessaging.unitypackage` and import all of it.
6. Go to *File > Build Settings...* , select iOS and click on Switch Platform.
7. Open *Player Settings...* and set a *Bundle Identifier*.
8. *File > Save project*
9. Connect the iOS device to the computer.
10. *File > Build & Run*

---

The project build on Xcode will end on the error shown in the image below:

[image: Build error]

---

Tried in two different MacBooks and with multiple projects.

- Is there something that we can do?
- Is it an error that must be
  resolved by Google?

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors in your Unity console when you build your iOS app? Those can be important, even if it looks like your Xcode project builds correctly...

Comment: @ToddKerpelman Rechecked, the Unity console doesn't show any Firebase error, only three warnings related with camera and micro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Feb 27 a [new version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity) of the [Firebase Unity SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) has been released solving this error. Now the Unity project compiles without errors for iOS.

Comment: it solved pod issues for me when using the realtime database package, but there is still link errors on both unity cloud build and local mac os computer...which unity packages are you using ?

Comment: @jauboux Duplicate symbols maybe?